# What does "not funded by you" mean in Vanguard's college savings planner?

Tags: united-states, calculation, vanguard, 529-plan

What does the green area called "**Not funded by you**" represent in this type of college 529 calculator?

Source calculator [here](https://vanguard.wealthmsi.com/csp.php).

[image]

Comment: $600,000 for college for one person?  Can that be right?

Comment: @gerrit Input includes today's annual cost (60K), and expected cost increase (5% pa), which would make cost for the first year of tuition 60k*(1.05^17)=137.5K.

Comment: @David Is that realistic?  Do tuition fees really increase by 5% per year while inflation and interest is close to 0?

Comment: @gerrit Implicit in your question seems to be either an assumption that inflation will continue to be close to zero for 17 years, or request to forecast inflation over 17 years. I have no idea whether 5% is a reasonable assumption, but it doesn't seem totally wacky. Anyway, between 2000 and 2019, US inflation has been ~2%, but (eg) Cornell's fees have gone from 21K to >56K (http://irp.dpb.cornell.edu/university-factbook/tuition). No idea if that's representative. But makes 5% seem quite plausible assuming minimal inflation

Comment: @gerrit (even more illustrative is Cornell's resident fees. For an equivalent time frame: 2002 to 2019, resident fees nearly tripled)

Comment: @David Right.  There's something deeply flawed with the US higher education system, and it hopes that flaw will be corrected before college costs $600k.

Comment: @gerrit The USA is experiencing deflation in transportable goods and significant inflation in non-transportable goods due to trade with China and other BRIC nations and emerging economies (I'll use BRIC as short hand); the cost of labour in BRIC is very low, so any good you can manufacture there has had its price collapse.  Monetary policy decisions produces "more cash" until *average* inflation is just above zero; with a massive downward pressure on transportable goods, this leads to inflation in non-transporable goods.  Housing, health care, education, ...

Comment: @gerrit Keep in mind that these are Ivy League numbers, not normal U.S. school numbers. While their academics are top-notch, you're really paying more for the name and making connections with wealthy people than for the actual education in that case. Also, it's unlikely that capacity in Ivy League schools will keep up with population and wealthy growth, so their prices will increase significantly faster than inflation due to the exclusivity (as they have in the past.)

Comment: @gerrit These figures are many times what most U.S. students pay for higher education. When I graduated in 2008, the tuition at my engineering school was about $5k, for example (and that's before accounting for the scholarships, which were actually significantly more than the tuition, to the point that I was paid several thousand a year to go there.)

Comment: @reirab these trends are by no means confined to the Ivy League. Consider the price history of U Michigan Ann Arbor, for instance: https://www.collegetuitioncompare.com/trends/university-of-michigan-ann-arbor/cost-of-attendance/ -- 20% (instate) and 30% (out-of-state) price increases in the previous 10 years. https://research.collegeboard.org/trends/college-pricing/highlights indicates $10.5k average in-state and $27k average out-of-state tuition and fees. None of this includes room and board (with housing being another class of product that is massively inflating in the past 30 years.)

Comment: @Tiercelet The trend of increasing prices certainly isn't limited to Ivy League (though they are increasing faster in Ivy League, due to inherently limited supply.) However, the $60k/yr starting prices used for the projections here are mostly just limited to the Ivy League and similar. Price increases over time will happen everywhere (barring a depression or some such major catastrophe,) but the $600k prices in the projections here certainly won't be the case outside of Ivy League schools and similar.

Comment: @reirab again, you're underestimating the extent and impact of the trend. https://www.collegetuitioncompare.com/trends/university-of-kentucky/cost-of-attendance/#COA shows the *current* cost of attendance (w/ living costs) for U Kentucky is $50k for out-of-state students. And school officials are not unaware of the incentive to encourage out-of-state enrollments; note the steady increase in out-of-state attendance (https://www.uky.edu/irads/enrollment-demographics). This isn't a problem confined to elite schools, unless your definition of elite includes "the average state university."

Comment: @Tiercelet Out-of-state tuition does indeed tend to be pretty expensive, since they're not paying the taxes that are providing most of the funding for the state schools. Still, though, you are massively overestimating averages. The average for out-of-state tuition and fees at state schools for the 2020-2021 academic year is [$27,020](https://www.collegedata.com/resources/pay-your-way/whats-the-price-tag-for-a-college-education). For in-state, it's $10,560 (same source.)

Comment: @Tiercelet Living costs are another matter. While you obviously do have to plan for them, they are generally unrelated to tuition and were not the topic of the comments I was replying to. Obviously, those will vary dramatically by location. The numbers that were under discussion earlier were just tuition and fees, so they're not comparable to numbers that include cost of living estimates (which are intentionally estimated on the high side because they are usually used as the absolute limit for financial aid a student can receive.)

Comment: @reirab  The screenshot says "public, 4-year, in-state", so I understood it to be about a regular public college, nothing elite.

Comment: @gerrit It looks like the $60k number has been typed in manually. That would be Ivy League tuition (as with the $56k mentioned for Cornell in the comments - Cornell is Ivy League.) As noted above, the average current in-state tuition for a public 4-year university is about $10.5k (though may be more or less depending on region.) And, again, that's before scholarships and such.

Comment: @reirab $60K is not even that high compared to other institutions. The estimated costs to go to Stanford are **$79K** per year for the '21/'22 academic year: https://financialaid.stanford.edu/undergrad/budget/index.html

Comment: @Josh Again, that's counting living expenses. Stanford is in the SF Bay Area. Living expenses there are through the roof (also, while not part of the actual "Ivy League" conference, Stanford is very much in that tier of schools.) You can, of course, easily spend $50-$60k/yr on tuition if you want to go to a private, Ive League-tier school, but that's very much the exception and not the rule. As shown above, the average in-state tuition and fees for a state university for the current academic year is $10.5k.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One of the items on the left hand side is "% of cost you plan to cover" which you've set to 50%.  So you're expecting that half the cost will be covered by someone else.  That's the "Not funded by you" section of the results.

This "Not funded by you" number includes things like financial aid, scholarships, loans.  Basically anything that is paying for college that isn't your savings.

Comment: Gifts from relatives, college funds previously funded by parents, GoFundMe campaigns, and the like.